# Cannot Start Android Emulator on Android Studio Version 2.3.3 After Android Oreo Installation

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.3, android-8.0-oreo

I am unable start `android emulator` on `android version 2.3.3` after `android Oreo` installation.

At first it worked,but now after a weekend when i ran a project the `emulator` doesn't pop up.

`AVD` loading notification is shown as in the below screenshot(dummy screenshot image in reality the notification is different)

[image]

But it will not appear,I have completely installed every package related to `android Oreo` in the `sdk tool manager`

[image]

Still the same result,if anyone has the same issue and have found a solution.Please,help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use cmd command like

```
*path_to_your_android_sdk*\tools\emulator -avd *device_name, f.e Nexus_5_API_23*
```

It should give you some detailed output about what happened wrong or would launch emulator.

Also make sure you are using last version of emulator (you have added screenshots only for SDK).

[image: Screenshot for updating emulator]

If nothing works - just remove all related to emulator sdk tools and reinstall them.